# Trouble settings content hugging and compression for labels in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am having issues getting my head around content compression and resistance on labels. Consider:

```
let label1 = UILabel()
label1.text = "hello"
label1.textColor = .white
label1.backgroundColor = .red

let label2 = UILabel()
label2.text = "bye"
label2.textColor = .white
label2.backgroundColor = .blue
```

These labels are in a horizontal stack view.

`let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2`])

This gives the following:

[image]

I want the red label to hug the content and never compress. I add this:

```
label1.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

[image]

Looks good so far but when the text is too long in the blue label I get this:

[image]

I tried setting `label1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)` but it makes no difference.

What am I doing wrong here? Would love some advice on how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry it's a stack view, updated the question

Comment: If you want the red label to not compress, just give it minimum width and add to stack view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultHigh` is not enough priority in this case. Set it to `required` instead.

```
label1.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
label1.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

[image]